# Why activity options are disabled?

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

I want to create a basic activity but this option is disable !
How can i fix that.

[Pic of SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpkk8.png)

[Pic of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdZ5j.png)

Answer (score 0):

**I think you have gradle Error. try to first solve the gradle Error, After that Just try to install all the SDKs ..but If you don't have much MB try to install from Sdk 19 to 25...**

Comment: But have you try to install all sdks or at least min sdk fro 19 to 20+